# Unsure why this code for enemy following player doesn't function as expected (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry if the answer is extremely obvious, I'm new to programming and this is the first question I've asked on here.
I've been following a tutorial on how to make a 2D maze game using Unity and I had no problems up until i tried to implement a simple AI enemy to follow the player. For some reason the enemy travels towards the player for a very short while before getting stuck in the maze walls.

A gif showing what I mean:
https://gyazo.com/78b4300c1aaa463db9342d3bddb8d28f

The enemy script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Transform target;
    void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (MazeGenerator.instance.GetMazeGridCell(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(transform.position.x)), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(transform.position.y))))
        {
            transform.position = UnityEngine.Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MazeRunner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkSpeed;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public Transform rotationTransform;
    Vector2 direction = Vector2.zero;
    int targetX = 1;
    int targetY = 1;

    int currentX = 1;
    int currentY = 1;
    float currentAngle;
    float lastAngle;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        bool targetReached = transform.position.x == targetX && transform.position.y == targetY;
        currentX = Mathf.FloorToInt(transform.position.x);
        currentY = Mathf.FloorToInt(transform.position.y);
        direction.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        direction.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        float angle = 0;

        if (direction.x > 0)
        {
            angle = 270;

            if (MazeGenerator.instance.GetMazeGridCell(currentX + 1, currentY) && targetReached)
            {
                targetX = currentX + 1;
                targetY = currentY;
            }
        }
        else if (direction.x < 0)
        {
            angle = 90;

            if (MazeGenerator.instance.GetMazeGridCell(currentX - 1, currentY) && targetReached)
            {
                targetX = currentX - 1;
                targetY = currentY;
            }
        }
        else if (direction.y > 0)
        {
            angle = 0;

            if (MazeGenerator.instance.GetMazeGridCell(currentX, currentY + 1) && targetReached)
            {
                targetX = currentX;
                targetY = currentY + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (direction.y < 0)
        {
            angle = 180;

            if (MazeGenerator.instance.GetMazeGridCell(currentX, currentY - 1) && targetReached)
            {
                targetX = currentX;
                targetY = currentY - 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            angle = lastAngle;
        }
        currentAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentAngle, angle, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(targetX, targetY), walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        rotationTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, currentAngle);
        lastAngle = angle;

    }
}
```

The maze generator script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MazeGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static MazeGenerator instance;

    public int mazeWidth;
    public int mazeHeight;
    public string mazeSeed;

    public Sprite floorSprite;
    public Sprite roofSprite;
    public Sprite wallSprite;
    public Sprite wallCornerSprite;

    public MazeSprite mazeSpritePrefab;

    System.Random mazeRG;

    Maze maze;

    public Vector3 mazeGoalPosition;

    public delegate void MazeReadyAction();
    public static event MazeReadyAction OnMazeReady;

    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        mazeRG = new System.Random();

        if (mazeWidth % 2 == 0)
            mazeWidth++;

        if (mazeHeight % 2 == 0)
        {
            mazeHeight++;
        }

        maze = new Maze(mazeWidth, mazeHeight, mazeRG);
        maze.Generate();

        mazeGoalPosition = maze.GetGoalPosition();

        DrawMaze();

        if (OnMazeReady != null)
        {
            OnMazeReady();
        }
    }

    void DrawMaze()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == true)
                {
                    CreateMazeSprite(position, floorSprite, transform, 0, mazeRG.Next(0, 3) * 90);
                }
                else
                {
                    CreateMazeSprite(position, roofSprite, transform, 0, 0);

                    DrawWalls(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void DrawWalls(int x, int y)
    {
        bool top = GetMazeGridCell(x, y + 1);
        bool bottom = GetMazeGridCell(x, y - 1);
        bool right = GetMazeGridCell(x + 1, y);
        bool left = GetMazeGridCell(x - 1, y);

        Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, y);

        if (top)
        {
            CreateMazeSprite(position, wallSprite, transform, 1, 0);
        }

        if (left)
        {
            CreateMazeSprite(position, wallSprite, transform, 1, 90);
        }

        if (bottom)
        {
            CreateMazeSprite(position, wallSprite, transform, 1, 180);
        }

        if (right)
        {
            CreateMazeSprite(position, wallSprite, transform, 1, 270);
        }

        if (!left && !top && x > 0 && y < mazeHeight - 1)
        {
            CreateMazeSprite(position, wallCornerSprite, transform, 2, 0);
        }

        if (!left && !bottom && x > 0 && y > 0)
        {
            CreateMazeSprite(position, wallCornerSprite, transform, 2, 90);
        }

        if (!right && !bottom && x < mazeWidth - 1 && y > 0)
        {
            CreateMazeSprite(position, wallCornerSprite, transform, 2, 180);
        }

        if (!right && !top && x < mazeWidth - 1 && y < mazeHeight - 1)
        {
            CreateMazeSprite(position, wallCornerSprite, transform, 2, 270);
        }
    }

    public bool GetMazeGridCell(int x, int y)
    {
        return maze.GetCell(x, y);
    }

    public List<Vector3> GetRandomFloorPositions(int count)
    {
        List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 position = Vector3.one;

            do
            {
                int posX = 0;
                int posY = 0;

                while (!GetMazeGridCell(posX, posY))
                {
                    posX = mazeRG.Next(3, mazeWidth);
                    posY = mazeRG.Next(3, mazeHeight);
                }

                position = new Vector3(posX, posY);
            } while (positions.Contains(position));

            positions.Add(position);
        }

        return positions;
    }

    void CreateMazeSprite(Vector3 position, Sprite sprite, Transform parent, int sortingOrder, float rotation)
    {
        MazeSprite mazeSprite = Instantiate(mazeSpritePrefab, position, Quaternion.identity) as MazeSprite;
        mazeSprite.SetSprite(sprite, sortingOrder);
        mazeSprite.transform.SetParent(parent);
        mazeSprite.transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotation);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any more aspects of my project or code are needed to help me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Seems that after a while the condition met in the `if (MazeGenerator.instance.GetMazeGridCell(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(transform.position.x)), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(transform.position.y))))` is not being met. I think you should debug and check that out